# Haskell basic typeclass primer (quadratic equations)

Tags: beginner, haskell

I have written Haskell code to my spec to help me grasp types and syntax, because I am learning.
I hope to generalize it further to accommodate more kinds of equations. I am (perhaps prematurely) worried that repeated usage of `delta` in multiple places is going to slow down my code, but I don't see how I can avoid it.

I am a bit confused about whether I should use `Floating` class or just use `Float` concrete type everywhere.

I appreciate any and all tips.

Here's the expected output

```
Equation -10.0x^2 +4.0x +1.0 = 0 has following 2 solutions:
0.28708285
-8.708288e-2
```

And the code

```
-- MathPrimer

delta :: Floating a => a -> a -> a -> a
x1 :: Floating a => a -> a -> a -> a
x2 :: Floating a => a -> a -> a -> a

delta a b c = b * b - 4 * a * c

x1 a b c = ( - b - sqrt(delta a b c)) / ( 4 * a * c )
x2 a b c = ( - b + sqrt(delta a b c)) / ( 4 * a * c )


class Algebraic equ where
    algebraicForm :: equ -> String

class (ZeroEquation equ) where
    solve :: equ -> [Float]
    solutionCount :: equ -> Int


data Equation = Quadratic {a :: Float, b :: Float, c :: Float}
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

instance (ZeroEquation Equation) where
    solve (Quadratic a b c) = solutions
        where
            both = [x1 a b c, x2 a b c]
            one = [x1 a b c]
            zero = []
            solutions = if _delta < 0 then zero else if _delta == 0 then one else both
            _delta = (delta a b c)
    solutionCount (Quadratic a b c) = count
        where
            count = if _delta < 0 then 0 else if _delta == 0 then 1 else 2
            _delta = (delta a b c)

instance (Algebraic Equation) where
    algebraicForm (Quadratic a b c) = show a ++ "x^2 +" ++ show b ++ "x +" ++ show c

showEquation :: Equation -> String
showEquation equ = "Equation " ++ description ++ " = 0 has following " ++ count ++ " solutions:\n" ++ solutions
    where
        count = show $ solutionCount equ
        description = algebraicForm equ
        solutions = unlines $ map show $ solve equ

main = do
    let equation = Quadratic (-10) 4 1
    putStrLn $ showEquation equation
```

Comment: Welcome to posting on Code Review (long time lurker, I see!).  Just out of interest, since I don't do Haskell myself - does this find only the real roots, or will it find complex roots where they exist?

Comment: only real, but I just have to substitute `sqrt` for a complex one to get complex. But I decided against it because it was no fun when there's only 2 or 0 solutions. I also would have to adjust `Float` and `Floating` to some complex types I don't know yet.

Comment: Also thank you very much! Code Review can be very helpful with learning I saw so I decided to try it myself @TobySpeight

Comment: No problem - I'm just taking the opportunity to learn something about Haskell.  Micro-review: consider changing the word "solutions" to "solution" when b² = 4ac.  How would you ensure that the message is translatable (remembering that different languages inflect by number very differently)?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell if the compiler would be able to eliminate duplicate calls to delta. It may do that, by inlining the `x1` and `x2` functions and then eliminating common subexpressions. Personally though, I prefer to do this myself. The following modification is guaranteed to call `delta` only once:

```
solve (Quadratic a b c) = solutions
    where
        both = [x1, x2]
        one = [x1]
        zero = []
        solutions = if _delta < 0 then zero else if _delta == 0 then one else both
        _delta = (delta a b c)
        x1 = ( - b - sqrt _delta) / ( 4 * a * c )
        x2 = ( - b + sqrt _delta) / ( 4 * a * c )
```

Comment: That's a fair suggestion. I guess I'll have to resort to benchmarking.